# StringtoWordVector() implementation in java

Tags: java, weka

If I simply write
filter = new StringToWordVector();
does this filter contain stopword algorithm and stemmer algorithm by default
or I have to particularly specify?

Comment: No. The default stopword removal is null and you need to specify stemming algorithm. Check the `StringToWordVector` javadoc.

Comment: how can I use stopwords from Rainbow?